# A realtime multiplayer game using XMPP on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, real-time, multiplayer

Theoretically speaking, is such a thing possible?

I know that Google App Engine can't make socket connections, so I figured using XMPP to send messages to the clients would work. Is XMPP on Google App engine low-latency enough to work for a realtime game?

I was looking into multiplayer game servers like Smartfox and the like, but I figured that the cost of the software combined with running it on my own server would be too much of a hassle, so I figured that running it on Google's hardware would be a good idea.

If you have any other suggestions on realtime multiplayer game servers, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Google's free quota is 3,000 XMPP messages per minute (50 per second), and their paid quota is 10x that. Trying to write a game server on that wouldn't really scale - assuming 1 message per second (which is probably low for any truly real-time game), that'd be a maximum of 50 or 500 clients respectively at any given time.

Comment: I don't know for XMPP, but there's a Quake demo that uses WebSockets. http://code.google.com/p/quake2-gwt-port/

Comment: Thanks Amber.

@zneak
Yes, but that demo doesn't run on app engine.

I'm interested in a server for a iPhone/Android game.  Would App Engine be a suitable platform for such an application?  If so, what protocol would I use for realtime server?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't know. If I had a better idea, I'd have posted an answer. :/

Comment: Details are light, but Google has recently announced the Channel API, which allows pushing messages over HTTP using long-polling requests (a la Comet). Not sure if that would be real-time enough, but it's a possibility. http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/05/app-engine-at-google-io-2010.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As npdoty points out, we've just announced the Channel API, which is intended for exactly this use-case. It's not released yet, but a preliminary version is available in the latest SDK for you to experiment with. There's no documentation yet, but you can explore the [Trivia Quiz](https://code.google.com/p/trivia-quiz/) sample app to see how it works.